# Splitting Tables For Multiple Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to save multiple entities in one table. Some of them are 1:1 correlation but some have certain fields so from a high level it looks like this.

```
Table
------
Key
Type 
A
B
C
D

Entity 1 (Where Type is 1)
------
Key
Type
A

Entity 2 (Where Type is 2)
------
Key
Type
A
B

Entity 3 (Where Type is 3)
------
Key
Type
B
C
D
```

Entity Framework is not a fan since E1, E2, and E3 are all mapped to the same table and throws this error.

*The entity types 'E1' and 'E2' cannot share table 'Table' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.*

So I have read about table splitting but it doesn't seem to work if you have entities that share properties and I can't find any good resources that aren't 'code first'. Furthermore, there seems to be no way to not include other fields not relevant to an entity as table splitting examples seem to require virtuals to other entities. Also there is nothing that might handling filtering out based on type that I can find. Any ideas on doing something like this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the associations and multiplicities, but I think you need an abstract type without A, B, C or D and make all types inherit from it.

Comment: This is what I did. I want to use TPH model but I can't figure out how to get it to work. Inspite of my attempts I keep getting Invalid column name discriminator error.

Comment: Have you any hint about a solution if you've found one?

Comment: @Rabskatran I believe upgrading to the latest entity framework allows you to do this.